# How enable `%` and `localhost` for the same Mysql user account

Tags: php, mysql, database

To create a user account in Mysql that can connect from any host, you provide `%`

```
CREATE USER 'newname'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpass'"
```

For recent version of Mysql there is a difference between using % and localhost for the user account host. My question is : How to create a user account with both `%` and `localhost` as host ?

NB: I don't want to create tow accounts for the same user but different host, I find it illogical with great number of users.

Any helpful hint please.

Comment: `create user newname@localhost`, basically. user accounts in mysql are composite: `(username, hostname)`. `user@127.0.0.1` and `user@localhost` would be recognized as two completely different accounts, because the two strings are different, even though they would still be the "same" account.

Comment: so if  a user attempts to connect with user@127.0.0.1 where his row in mysql users table is `%|user|pass|...` it will be accepted ?

Comment: `user@%` is a wildcard account: that particular user, from ANYWHERE (local/network). not sure how mysql evaluates conflicting entries, e.g. `user@%` plus `user@localhost`. never tested out that scenario.

Comment: I gave it a try even with `user@127.0.0.1` it gives : access denied for `'user'@'@localhost'`

Comment: mysql does have a "feature" where it translates `localhost` to mean a local unix-domain socket instead of a tcp connection. that might be causing some issues.